# Extract part of Text in HTML using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have HTML as :

```
<span id="lbldiv" class="lbl" style="color:Blue;">
    Division : First; Grand Total: 3861; Grand Max Total: 4600
</span>
```

I can extract the text : `Division : First; Grand Total: 3861; Grand Max Total: 4600` by using the `get_text` on the span element.

Is it possible to extract just the numbers - `3861` and `4600` from the text or get the characters(numbers) by skipping the alphabets using Beautiful Soup library in Python?

Comment: You could do this using some string processing options like `str.split()`, but depending on how complex / consistent the data is, it may be better to use a regular expression.

Comment: Use `text = soup.find("span", {"id":"lbldiv"}).text` to get the text. Then you can get the numbers with the `split` and `isdigit` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is regular, and by the looks of it, it's key-value pairs separated by semi-colons. The function below will extract that into key-value tuples. You could then go through and extract only rows where there are numbers using something like the below.

```
def extract_kv_pairs(s):
    """Extract key value pairs seperated by colons and semi-colons."""
    kvp = []
    for r in s.split(';'):
        k, v = r.split(':')
        # is it an integer?
        try:
            # yes, convert it
            v = int(v)
        except ValueError:
            # no, trim the string
            v = v.strip()

        kvp.append((k.strip(), v))

    return kvp

s = 'Division : First; Grand Total: 3861; Grand Max Total: 4600'
kvp = extract_kv_pairs(s)
numeric_values = [p for p in kvp if isinstance(p[1], int)]
print(kvp)
# [('Division', 'First'), ('Grand Total', 3861), ('Grand Max Total', 4600)]
print(numeric_values)
# [('Grand Total', 3861), ('Grand Max Total', 4600)]
```